# How to plot R's vegan::procrustes using Python (SciPy, NumPy, and Matplotlib)?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, scipy, vegan

I'm following the vegan tutorial on procrustes analysis:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/vegan/versions/2.4-2/topics/procrustes

```
# Load data
library(vegan)
data(varespec)

# Ordinations
vare.dist <- vegdist(wisconsin(varespec))
mds.null <- monoMDS(vare.dist, y = cmdscale(vare.dist))
mds.alt <- monoMDS(vare.dist)

# Run procrustes
vare.proc <- procrustes(mds.alt, mds.null)

# Summary of procrustes
summary(vare.proc)
Call:
procrustes(X = mds.alt, Y = mds.null)

Number of objects: 24    Number of dimensions: 2

Procrustes sum of squares:
 13.99951
Procrustes root mean squared error:
 0.7637492
Quantiles of Procrustes errors:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max
0.08408327 0.23038165 0.49316643 0.65854198 1.99105837

Rotation matrix:
          [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.9761893  0.2169202
[2,] 0.2169202 -0.9761893

 of averages:
              [,1]          [,2]
[1,] -2.677059e-17 -5.251452e-18

Scaling of target:
[1] 0.6455131

plot(vare.proc)
```

[image]

Now with Python I can choose either:

- [scipy.spatial.procrustes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.procrustes.html)

```
# Returns
mtx1: array_like
A standardized version of data1.

mtx2: array_like
The orientation of data2 that best fits data1. Centered, but not necessarily .

disparity: float
 as defined above.
```

- [scipy.linalg.orthogonal_procrustes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.orthogonal_procrustes.html)

```
R(N, N): ndarray
The matrix solution of the orthogonal Procrustes problem. Minimizes the Frobenius norm of (A @ R) - B, subject to R.T @ R = I.

scale: float
Sum of the singular values of A.T @ B.
```

**My questions:**

- Which implementation is more similar to `vegan::procrustes`,  `scipy.spatial.procrustes` or `scipy.linalg.orthogonal_procrustes`?
- How is the output used to generate the figure above (in Matplotlib not via Rpy2)?

## EDIT:

Using [@Kat's answer for the plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70898722/678572) and [my additional answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70962511/678572) for the SciPy/NumPy implementation, one should be able to reproduce the VEGAN analysis in Python exactly using only standard packages from PyData.

## Edit 2:

Just in case it helps anyone, I've implemented both `Procrustes` and `Protest` (along with the plotting method described here) from `vegan` in my `soothsayer` python package:
https://github.com/jolespin/soothsayer/blob/60accb669062c559ba785be201deddeede26a049/soothsayer/ordination/ordination.py#L715

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manner in which the `vegan` package runs through `monoMDS` doesn't seem to align with any of the methods that Python uses. The code in `vegan` is all based on Fortran. You could link the Fortan to Python, just like you can in R.

While the scaling is different, the rotation matrix within `vare.proc` is exactly the same as the rotation matrix (array?) in the Python coded object above `vare_proc`. I found that to be interesting.

If I bring in the pieces of the content in R for your object `vare.proc`, I can make the exact graph.

First, I used R Markdown to share objects between Python and R.

```
# compare to R
# vpR = vareProc$rotation
vpR_py = r.vpR    
# vpYrot = vareProc$Yrot
vpYrot_py = r.vpYrot
# vpX = vareProc$X
vpX_py = r.vpX
```

Then I used these objects to make the replica

```
# build the plot exactly like vegan 
# using https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/blob/master/R/plot.procrustes.R
tails = vpYrot_py
heads = vpX_py

# find the ranges
xMax = max(abs(np.hstack((tails[:,0], heads[:,0]))))
yMax = max(abs(np.hstack((tails[:,1], heads[:,1]))))

plt.figure(dpi = 100) 
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
ax.set_xlim(-xMax, xMax)
ax.set_ylim(-yMax, yMax)

# add points
ax.scatter(x = tails[:,0],
           y = tails[:,1],
           facecolors = 'none',
           edgecolors = 'k')

# add origin axes
ax.axhline(y = 0, color='k', ls = '--', linewidth = 1) # using dashed for origin
ax.axvline(x = 0, color='k', ls = '--', linewidth = 1)

# add rotation axes
ax.axline(xy1 = (0, 0), color = 'k',
          slope = vpR_py[0, 1]/vpR_py[0, 0])
ax.axline(xy1 = (0, 0), color = 'k',
          slope = vpR_py[1, 1]/vpR_py[1, 0])

# add arrows
for i in range(0, len(tails)):
  ax.annotate("", xy = heads[i,:],
              xycoords = 'data',
              xytext = tails[i,:], 
              arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",
                              color = 'blue'))

plt.tight_layout(pad = 2)
plt.show()
```

##### From `matplotlib`

[image]

##### From `vegan`

[image]

Comment: This is extremely helpful in understanding the plotting process. The only bit I'm still confused on is how to use the output from scipy.spatial.procrustes or scipy.linalg.orthogonal_procrustes. I noticed you used the procrustes package, is this implementation different than what is available in scipy?

Comment: I think I tried every version of the Procrustes algorithms that I could find. I felt that `procrustes.rotational` was the closest to what you were looking for. However, there are many ways to use these methods. There may be a better method than the one I went with.

Comment: Please see the edit I've made to the end of the question. I'm very close to accepting your answer. My only remaining question to be able to reproduce this using SciPy/NumPy entirely is how `Yrot` is calculated since `X` is the same as the input.

Comment: There is no line of Fortran in Procrustes analysis in vegan. (There is in monoMDS, but that is unrelated to Procrustes).

Comment: You're right @jari Oksanen, it's the function `monoMDS()` that has the Fortran I was referring to.

Comment: I accepted and upvoted for both of them. Thanks for your patience. I figured out the Yrot problem (check the extra answer for details)

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the same, but I think it's pretty close.

I brought the `varespec` data into Python for this. Then tried to mimic the actions that the `vegan` package (and your code) took. Along those lines, I stuck to the object names you used (for the most part).

There has to be an easier way to do this.

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd
import sklearn.manifold as sm #  MDS, smacof
import procrustes
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

wVares_py = r.wVares # I brought in the varespec data from R (named wVares)
# find the distance
vare_dist = ssd.pdist(wVares_py, 'braycurtis')
# make it square (Required for MDS and smaof
vare_dist = ssd.squareform(vare_dist)

mds = sm.MDS(metric = False, dissimilarity = 'precomputed')
mds_alt = mds.fit_transform(vare_dist)
mds_null = sm.smacof(vare_dist, metric = False, init = mds_alt)

vare_proc = procrustes.rotational(mds_alt, mds_null[0], translate = False)

# create an array that represents the axes at the origin, then rotate them
xAx = np.array([[-.4, 0],[.4, 0]])
yAx = np.array([[0, .4], [0, -.4]])

# create the rotated origins
xHat = vare_proc["t"] * xAx
yHat = vare_proc["t"] * yAx

# add line segments
vareA = pd.DataFrame(vare_proc.new_a, columns = ['x1', 'y1'])
vareB = pd.DataFrame(vare_proc.new_b, columns = ['x2', 'y2'])
df = pd.concat([vareA, vareB], axis = 1)

# now find the differences
df['dx'] = df.x2 - df.x1
df['dy'] = df.y2 - df.y1
```

Now everything's set for graphing.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10), dpi = 100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plot the points
# plot the points
ax.scatter(vare_proc.new_a[:, 0], 
           vare_proc.new_a[:, 1], 
           marker = 'o', 
           label = 'a', 
           c = '#cc5500')
# plot the x, y axes
ax.axhline(y=0, color='k')
ax.axvline(x=0, color='k')
# plot the rotated origin
ax.axline(xHat[:,0], xHat[:,1], linestyle = '-.')
ax.axline(yHat[:,0], yHat[:,1], linestyle = '-.')
# add arrows to show the direction per point
ax.quiver(df.x1, df.y1, df.dx, df.dy, units='xy', color = 'gray', scale=.7)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help with the answer. Hmm...do you know what the discrepancy could be?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. To what are you referring?

Comment: When you mention "It's not exactly the same, but I think it's pretty close" and the small differences in arrow lengths of the plots between R and Python.

Comment: You have ran a complex analysis and any component could differ. However, there are many variants of NMDS and we use Kruskal's original. I don't know what you have used, and it may be harder to find out.  Neither do I know how you have handled the convergence issues in Python (it looks that they are not handled: cannot see any code to do so). You better check Python documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to reproduce the `vegan` `procrustes` analysis in Python using only `SciPy` and `NumPy`. Please refer to @Kat answers above for context on how to plot:

```py
# Get X and Y which are the first 2 embeddings
# -------------------------------------------
# X <- scores(X, display = scores, ...)
mds_null = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/c1Zwb4pu", index_col=0, sep="\t")
X_original = mds_null.values
# X_original[:5]
# array([[-0.28600328, -0.23135498],
#        [ 0.00510282, -0.39170001],
#        [ 0.80888622,  1.18656269],
#        [ 1.44897916, -0.18887702],
#        [ 0.54496396, -0.09403705]])

# Y <- scores(X, display = scores, ...)
mds_alt = pd.read_csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/UMGLgXmu", index_col=0, sep="\t")
Y_original = mds_alt.values
# Y_original[:5]
# array([[ 0.2651293 ,  0.09755548],
#        [ 0.17639036,  0.45328207],
#        [-0.16167398, -1.42304932],
#        [-1.44706047,  0.3966337 ],
#        [-0.49825949,  0.15239689]])


# Procrustes in VEGAN
# ----------------
procrustes_result = vegan.procrustes(X_original, Y_original, scale=True, symmetric=False, scores="sites")

# Rotation matrix from VEGAN
A = np.array(dict(procrustes_result.items())["rotation"])
# A
# # array([[-0.98171787, -0.19034186],
# #        [ 0.19034186, -0.98171787]])

# Center the X and Y data
# -----------------------
X_mean = X_original.mean(axis=0)
X = X_original - X_mean
Y_mean = Y_original.mean(axis=0)
Y = Y_original - Y_mean

# # Rotation matrix from SciPy
# ----------------------------
A, sca = orthogonal_procrustes(X,Y)
# A
# array([[-0.98171787,  0.19034186],
#        [-0.19034186, -0.98171787]])


# Manual calculation
# ------------------
# np.linalg.svd returns:
# u{ (…, M, M), (…, M, K) } array
# Unitary array(s). The first a.ndim - 2 dimensions have the same size as those of the input a. The size of the last two dimensions depends on the value of full_matrices. Only returned when compute_uv is True.

# s(…, K) array
# Vector(s) with the singular values, within each vector sorted in descending order. The first a.ndim - 2 dimensions have the same size as those of the input a.

# vh{ (…, N, N), (…, K, N) } array
# Unitary array(s). The first a.ndim - 2 dimensions have the same size as those of the input a. The size of the last two dimensions depends on the value of full_matrices. Only returned when compute_uv is True.

XY = np.dot(X.T, Y) # crossprod(X,Y)
U,s,Vh = np.linalg.svd(XY)
V = Vh.T
A = np.dot(V, U.T)
# A
# array([[-0.98171787, -0.19034186],
#        [ 0.19034186, -0.98171787]])

# Reproduce the Yrot object
# -------------------------
scale = True
symmetric = False

# Yrot from VEGAN
Yrot = np.array(dict(procrustes_result.items())["Yrot"])
# Yrot[:5]
# array([[-0.20919556, -0.12656386],
#        [-0.07519809, -0.41418755],
#        [-0.09706039,  1.23572329],
#        [ 1.29483042, -0.098617  ],
#        [ 0.44844991, -0.04740275]])

# NumPy implementation
# ctrace <- function(MAT) sum(MAT^2)
def ctrace(MAT):
    return np.sum(MAT**2)

# if (scale) {
#     c <- sum(sol$d)/ctrace(Y)
if scale:
    c = np.sum(s)/ctrace(Y)

# Yrot <- c * Y %*% A
Yrot = c * np.dot(Y,A)
Yrot[:5]
# array([[-0.20919556, -0.12656386],
#        [-0.07519809, -0.41418755],
#        [-0.09706039,  1.23572329],
#        [ 1.29483042, -0.098617  ],
#        [ 0.44844991, -0.04740275]])
```

Answer (score 0):

### Another Implementation of PROTEST for python

Thanks for sharing! In case anyone is interested, here is my implementation of PROTEST that I worked out upon @O.rka's work after cross-checking literature and the VEGAN implementation.

```
from tqdm import trange

def protest(X, Y, no_permutations=999, with_replacement=False):
    '''Performs procrustean test (PROTEST).

    H_0: "X and Y are no more related than random datasets would be."
    
    Args:
        X (np.ndarray):             Matrix of shape (n x p11), where n is the number of observations
        Y (np.ndarray):             Matrix of shape (n x p12)
        no_permutations (int):      Number of permutations to consider
        with_replacement (bool):    If set to True, permutations are sampled with replacement.

    Returns:
        test_statistic (float):          Procrustean correlation coefficient
        p_value (float):    P-Value of PROTEST
        RSS (float):        Residual Sum of Squares of prucrustes rotations

    References:
        Gower & Dijksterhuis (2004):    "Procrustes Problems"
        Gower (1971):                   "Statistical methods of comparing different multivariate analyses 
                                            of the same data", p. 138-149
        Peres-Neto & Jackson (2001):    "How well do multivariate data sets match? The advantages of 
                                            a Procrustean superimposition approach over the Mantel test"   
    '''
    n = X.shape[0]
    assert n == Y.shape[0], 'X has to be of shape (n x p1) and Y has to be of shape (n x p2).'

    # Get machine float error
    EPS = np.sqrt(np.finfo(float).eps)

    # # standardize the matrices using Gower-Transformation (Gower 1971)
    X, Y = gower_trafo(X), gower_trafo(Y)

    # calculate test statistic & residual sum of squares
    test_statistic = procrustes_corr(X, Y)
    RSS = np.sum(X**2) + np.sum(
        Y**2) - 2 * test_statistic  # c.f. Gower & Dijksterhuis (2004), equation 4.3

    # Get integer index for permutations
    index = np.arange(0, n)

    # Permute and calculate goodness of fit
    permutations = list()
    for rs in trange(no_permutations):
        permutated_idx = np.random.RandomState(rs).choice(index, replace=with_replacement, size=n)
        corr = procrustes_corr(X[permutated_idx], Y)
        permutations.append(corr)
    permutations = np.array(permutations)

    p_value = (np.sum(permutations >= test_statistic - EPS) + 1) / (no_permutations + 1)

    # Print Output
    print(f'Performed PROTEST with {no_permutations} permutations.')
    print(f'Procrustean correlation coefficient: {test_statistic}')
    print(f'p-Value: {p_value}')
    print(f'Residual Sum of Squares: {RSS}')

    return test_statistic, p_value, RSS


def procrustes_corr(X, Y):
    '''Calculates the procrustean correlation coefficient.
    
    Args:
        X (np.ndarray):   Gower-transformed Matrix of shape (n x p1), where n is the number of observations
        Y (np.ndarray):   Gower-transformed Matrix of shape (n x p2)

    Returns:
        corr (float):    The goodness of fit of the orthogonal procrustes rotation. Procrustean form of Corelation coefficient.

    References:
        Peres-Neto & Jackson (2001):    "How well do multivariate data sets match? The advantages of 
                                        a Procrustean superimposition approach over the Mantel test"       
    '''
    XY = np.dot(X.T, Y)
    _, s, _ = np.linalg.svd(XY)

    # for performing PROTEST (Peres-Neto & Jackson 2001)
    corr = np.trace(np.diag(s))

    return corr


def gower_trafo(A):
    '''Standardizes Matrix A using Gower-Transformation.

    Args:
        A (np.ndarray):     Matrix of shape (n x p), where n is the number of observations

    Returns:
        A (np.ndarray):     Standardized Matrix A

    References:
        Gower (1971):       "Statistical methods of comparing different multivariate analyses 
                             of the same data", p. 138-149
    '''
    A = A - A.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)
    A = A / np.sqrt(np.sum(A**2))
    return A
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. Was my implementation of Protest incorrect? I have never used it before I implemented it so I'm not terribly familiar with the implementation. Mostly just tried to reimplement line-by-line and function-by-function from VEGAN.

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see your implementation was correct, especially the calculation of the p-value and the Residual Sum of Squares. I am not sure about the procrustean correlation coefficient. You report r = sqrt(1- RSS) whereas I decided to report r = trace(D), where D is the diagonal matrix of the computed SVD. But for me the literature is not clear on this...

Comment: Awesome, this is really helpful. I'll take another look at it when I get a second.